# JavaCV-OpenCV error

Tags: java, opencv, javacv

I want to capture my webcam on a easy way into Java.
I followed this tutorial with JavaCV and OpenCV: http://ganeshtiwaridotcomdotnp.blogspot.com/2011/12/opencv-javacv-eclipse-project.html

I get this error when trying some example code:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: C:\Users\Francis\AppData\Local\Temp\jniopencv_core7109340164936655704.dll: Can't find dependent libraries
        at java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0(ClassLoader.java:1807)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1703)
        at java.lang.Runtime.load0(Runtime.java:770)
        at java.lang.System.load(System.java:1003)
        at com.googlecode.javacpp.Loader.loadLibrary(Loader.java:403)
        at com.googlecode.javacpp.Loader.load(Loader.java:342)
        at com.googlecode.javacpp.Loader.load(Loader.java:316)
        at com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_core.<clinit>(opencv_core.java:131)
        at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:247)
        at com.googlecode.javacpp.Loader.load(Loader.java:335)
        at com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_imgproc.<clinit>(opencv_imgproc.java:96)
        at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:247)
        at com.googlecode.javacpp.Loader.load(Loader.java:335)
        at com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_highgui.<clinit>(opencv_highgui.java:91)
        at com.googlecode.javacv.OpenCVFrameGrabber.start(OpenCVFrameGrabber.java:171)
        at beeldherkenningp1.CaptureImage.captureFrame(CaptureImage.java:13)
        at beeldherkenningp1.BeeldherkenningP1.main(BeeldherkenningP1.java:37)
```

But al my jar's are included,  Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 Redistributable Package is installed, extracted OpenCV into root and my system Path is set correct... (tryed already several times to reinstal the Visual C++ Redistributable Package). (x64 bit, does it matter Netbeans is x86?)

Or does anybody know an other lib that **easily** captures a cam in java?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: If you run your code in a x86 JVM, you'll need the x86 version of the redistribuables as well as of OpenCV.

Comment: Now, I've both installed the x64 and the x86 of the Microsoft Visual C++ Redistr Package, could that give troubles?

Comment: It should not. It is only required that whatever architecture the JVM uses is available - the facto other architectures are available shouldn't cause trouble.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am the one who wrote the tutorial that you're following.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: 
C:\Users\Francis\AppData\Local\Temp\jniopencv_core7109340164936655704.dll: 
Can't find dependent libraries
```

It looks like the dll library is not in environment variable path because you didn't properly added the path of opencv. Or this might be issue because you have installed both x64 and x86  version of thet Visual C++ redistribuables that Romain is saying.

I suggest you to follow the steps I described here JavaCV : [eclipse project configuration windows](http://ganeshtiwaridotcomdotnp.blogspot.com/2011/12/opencv-javacv-eclipse-project.html) ? and Add the following to System Path ?

**Configure path**

```
64-bit version of the JDK:
[installation path]\build\common\tbb\intel64\vc10\;C:\opencv\build\x64\vc10\bin\;
32-bit version of the JDK:
[installation path]\build\common\tbb\ia32\vc10\;C:\opencv\build\x86\vc10\bin\;
```

Here `[installation path]` might be `"C:\opencv"`

Hope this helps.

**UPDATE:**

An easier and simpler step to configure JavaCV is available. Please check the link below:

- http://ganeshtiwaridotcomdotnp.blogspot.com/2017/01/javacv-configuration-in-windows.html

Comment: The problem was that I supposed my JDK was 64-bit (because of 64-bit windows), but netbeans told me it was x86... http://i.imgur.com/Srkve.png AND restarting the computer after adapting the path!

Comment: Yes! Now it works! But now I get this problem: The first time  I run the program after a computer restart it works very well. But it only works once, when I stop running the program, and run it again, it wouldn't work, I get an empty CanvasFrame... Do you have an idea of this issue? Thanks! (I use this code: http://ganeshtiwaridotcomdotnp.blogspot.com/2011/12/javacv-capture-save-flip-show-live.html)